# Query single entity through Breeze+Odata via .../Entity/1L url

Tags: odata, breeze

I am trying to load a single entity by its key from an OData server using BreezeJS. After some research, it seems that `EntityQuery.fromEntityKey` is the proper approach (since I also would want to add expand).

The intended query URL would be `http://.../Customer(1L)?$expand=...`.

However with the following code:

```js
let query = EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(new EntityKey("Customer", id)).expand("...")
return <Promise<Customer>><any> this.entityManager.executeQuery(query)
```

the URL is 
`http://.../Customer?$filter=CustomerId eq 1L & $expand=...`
which is not entirely incorrect, but different from what would normally be used to request an entity.

How can Breeze be configured/called to get the "correct" URL?

Comment: See [breeze.ajaxrestinterceptor.js](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.ajaxrestinterceptor.js)

Comment: Is that truly the recommended approach? The source file says "DO NOT USE. TOO PRIMITIVE AND NOT GOOD GUIDANCE. WILL BE DEPRECATED SOON". It feels strange that there is no configuration to support what I have seen as the de-facto standard URL for querying an entity by key.

Comment: Different OData implementations support different URL formats.  $filter is universal.  That file is a demonstration of how you can make the URL format whatever you want.